# How can I unpack texture data following a 16 * 8-bit pattern?

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl

Is possible to unpack texture data following a specific bit packing scheme?

I have read that texture data in HLSL can be read in as 4 floats of 32 bits each totaling 128 bits. The packing scheme I'm looking to use is 16 packing groups of 8 bits each. I am having trouble figuring out how to unpack this data without loss due to it being interpreted as floats.

Comment: This might be a bit challenging to pack into a single texture sample - particularly if you want to support a range of devices, as not every texture format is supported across the board. Are you able to repack (or re-interpret) the data as 4 textures of 4 8-bit components, or 4 taps from a single texture with double the dimensions? This would let you use widely-supported 8bpc formats that can round-trip between integer and float representation losslessly.

Comment: That sounds like it could be a good solution. I'm still mostly foggy on how I could implement this.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail about how this packed data is generated / what it represents / how it's unpacked, so we can tailor answers to be relevant to that context?

Comment: The data is used to identify the texture points as part of a group. e.i. It's a body texture so one group could be freckles and another could be laugh lines. Each texture point can be part of many groups. I wanted to know how unpacking would work before I combined the data into one texture so that I could tailor the data towards the solution. Each group will be colored using swatches so I don't need color data in these textures.

Comment: Oh wow! And how many of these groups occur in a single material?

Comment: I was thinking to future proof it by allowing each texture point to belong to at most 16 groups out of a set of 255 groups (the 0 group would mean no group). Realistically I'm going to start with only a few groups so I could get away with what it sounds like you are suggesting with the 4 8-bit components.

Comment: Does every group need an 8 bit intensity? Or can you get away with coarser gradations? It's sounding to me like you might get better answers by asking about your intended application "How do I dynamically recolour multiple marked regions on a texture?" than asking about your initial idea of the solution with bit-packing. If you include examples of the outputs you want to achieve, that can be a big help in evaluating which methods can produce those outcomes.